# ESLint: disable ECMA version features for overrides section in eslintrc

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint, ecmascript-5

We have a single (on purpose, so that it is consistently consumed by all tools -- from Webpack to IDEs) `.eslintrc` file.

We have two types of JS files this is expected to be used for: React JSX files, used for server rendering and vanilla JS files (ECMAScript 5) used for client-side enrichment.

Abridged (LOL) version looks something like this:

```
{
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 8,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true,
            "modules": true,
            ...            
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "browser": true,
        "mocha": true,
        "amd": true
    },
    "rules": {
        ...
    },
    "plugins": [..."react"...],
    "globals": {
        ...
        "requirejs": true
    },
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": ["src/*/assets/js/**/*.js"],
            "env": {
                "es6": false,
                "node": false,
                "browser": true,
                "jquery": true,
                "mocha": false,
                "amd": true
            },
            "parserOptions": {
                "ecmaVersion": 5,
                "sourceType": "script",
                "ecmaFeatures": {
                    "jsx": false,
                    "modules": false,
                    "experimentalObjectRestSpread": false
                }
            },
            "rules": {
                ...
            },
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

What we are trying to achieve (by using `overrides`) is that different set of rules are applied to React JSX code and vanilla JS, especially since they run in different environments.

**We are looking for a way to make ESLint fail when ES6+ features are used in client-side vanilla JS.**

Unfortunately, setting `parserOptions` or `env` on `overrides` doesn't have any effect. We can still use `const` and `=>` in our vanilla JS code that is supposed to be ECMAScript 5.

Is it something that can be achieved without splitting the `.eslintrc` into several files, or at all?

Comment: What is in your rules section? Why are you attempting to do this via overrides? Have you had a look at react plugin for eslint? Aptly named 'eslint-plugin-react'

Comment: @wmash for the reasons stated above. There are two **distinct** types of artefacts that require separate rules. Sometimes contradicting. For instance -- I want to be able to use arrow functions in React code, while disallowing it in vanilla files. It has nothing to do with plugins, but, yes, `eslint-plugin-react` is there and is properly used.

Comment: The best thing is to not mix these files together. Thus you can have two different eslintrc. This is how it's usually done.

Comment: @estus This approach will then require to mess around with IDEs, which expect a single `.eslintrc`, normally. I'd rather not. That introduces unnecessary friction. Also... the files do belong, conceptually, to the same component. Each component has React JSX code and client side code.